# How can I make a query like "array that contain no other values than" in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I hope I don't miss something obvious, but I haven't seen anywhere a syntax like that.

I'm working for an online courses provider where the user subscribes by topic.

- A course can have multiple topics
- User must have subscribed for **all** topics of that course to have access to it

I know how to make a request like `{ topics: { $nin : ...allTheTopicsUserHaveNoAccessTo } }` but that forces me to get all "not allowed" topics first.

Is there a way to make that kind of request in one call ?

---

User model:

```
const userModel = {
  allowedTopics: [ 'math', 'physics' ],
}
```

Course model:

```js
const courseModel = {
  topics: [ 'math', 'physics', 'biology' ], // user need to have subscribed to those three to see it
}
```

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. "contains no other fields" implies a query to analyse field names but the snippets of code are all about values within the "topics" field. Try to rephrase the question emphasising on document structure, queries and expected results rather than business requirements.

Comment: Ok I ll change that ^^ feel free to edit if you think you can improve clarity also :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setIsSubset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) does it in a single command and can be used in a regular `find` with [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) operator:

```
db.course.find({
  $expr: {
    $setIsSubset: [
      "$topics",
      user.allowedTopics
    ]
  }
})
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/JfSiSrboOuj

It still won't let you benefit from multikey indexes though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done.

Aggregation with `$setDifference` followed by a match for empty array will accomplish that.

However, such an aggregation pipeline would not be able to make use of an index, and would have to fetch from disk and examine every course in the entire catalog for every single run.

Comment: Thnks, however, could you provide some code example please ?